# Graphing Plugins For jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

Can anyone recommend any easy to use graph drawing plugins for jQuery? I am constructing a web app that will pull data from a remote database and display it in the form of a graph...

I have seen jgcharts (the jQuery Google Chart plugin) but there doesn't seem to be much documentation

Answer (score 2):

In my search for a easy to use jquery plotting library i have found jqplot and flot to be the easiest to use as well as have the most features.

JqPlot - http://www.jqplot.com/

Flot - http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page and take your pick:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Answer (score 0):

[gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) isn't written explicitly for jQuery, but it'll probably do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) uses jQuery as far as I know.
They have an amazing demo. Check it out, I use it for my Vaadin projects. When signing up for it, I found out they were using jQuery. It's not free but pretty reasonably priced.

Highcharts [demo page](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/).